# Minecraft: TAB name change

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a nickname plugin on this server and I have changed my name. Is there a way for me to change my name on TAB too? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like a plugin recommendation question, but sounds like one..

Comment: @aytimothy, op is asking if they can change their name. Hardly a plugin rec. If plugins are the only way to go, answer "only with plug ins, but asking for a rec is offtopix on here, maybe try a forum etc etc.."

Comment: @Timelord64 - It can be answered either ways: [Either as a Plugin Req](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/232868/75275) (scroll down) or as a programming question [by using the MC protocols](http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Player_List_Item), you can make the server send custom names to the client.

Comment: @aytimothy, it would be a good idea to detail the MC protocol as an answer, if it answers the problem. Especially if other answers are likely to be recommendations

Comment: @Timelord64 his question included him using a plugin to change chat name, so it was assumed he was looking for a plugin to change his list name.

Comment: @user3878893, he mentions using a plugin, but does not ask to use a plugin for the second action. My guess is he thought it was relevant to know that his server already has a name change. But its never a good idea to assume unless bleatingly obvious.

Comment: @Timelord64 ok, got it. But it looks like he didn't tell us the plugin he was using so I did not assume what you are saying.

Comment: @Timelord64 - Then this becomes a programming question, and I haven't used the APIs in a long time, so it may take awhile to dig through the documentation or to write a code sample.

Comment: @aytimothy, might I recommend something along the lines of "using programming, you can alter the API, reference this document, etc"? As I interpret this question, OP is not technically asking for a walkthrough of how to do it - rather, they are asking if they **can** do it. I would consider 'you can via programing, but the exact method is up to you to investigate, and asking so on here may be offtopic' to be an appropriate answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a plugin request I do say, but I'll recommend one anyways.

[ColoredTabList](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/coloredtablist/) includes the  command `coloredtablist nick <nickname>` . This Changes your Name in the Tablist until you reconnect or the Server reloads.

Comment: Probably worth commenting that I downvoted this for being a "recommendation" answer. Perhaps you could go along the lines of "You could use a plug in that does X, take ColoredTabList for example".